# Is it possible to add an attachment to an existing Task or Event?

Tags: attachment, tasks

Using the standard Salesforce interface for Tasks (Page Layout), there is a related list for Attachments. However, there's no button to add a new Attachment to an existing Task, and when I edit the Tasks Page layout the Attachments related list is "not customizable".

**Is there another way to add an attachment to a Task (or Event)?** I'd like to make sure I'm not missing anything using standard customization before using Apex/Visualforce.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to Edit the task itself to see the Add Attachment button. It's only available in the task edit view.

Comment: Perfect.. Knew I was missing something.